# Using Ajax to change title of topic in a forum javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

```
$(function(){
  var regex= /^\/t\d-/;
  var a = $('.post')[0];
  var b = $(a).find('.profile-icons')[0];
  var c = $(b).find('.i_icon_edit')[0];
  var testTitle = /^\[COMPLETED\]/i;
  var d = $('.page-title').find('a')[0].innerText;
   if(regex.test(window.location.pathname) && c && !testTitle.test(d)){
   var ahref = c.parentNode.href.replace('http://'+window.location.hostname,'');
   var complete = document.createElement('li');
   complete.id="completed";
   complete.setAttribute('onclick','markComplete("'+ahref+'")');
   complete.innerHTML="Mark Complete";
   b.appendChild(complete);
  }
});
  function markComplete(yhref){
   $.post(yhref,function(data){
     var val = $(data).find('input[name="subject"]').val();
     $(data).find('input[name="subject"]').val('[COMPLETED]'+val);
     $(data).find('input[name="edit_reason"]').val('User Marked Question as Completed');
     $(data).find('form[name="post"]').submit();
   }).done(function(){
   window.location.reload();
  });
 }
```

The actual code works, just not the function `markComplete` I stink at Ajax as I've havent had time to teach myself any of this yet. I just need to change the title of the topic in a forum, then reload the page as to save Ajax request. The reloading works just not the Ajax. I've read the documentation at jQuery.com just not fully understanding it yet. Can anyone help me with finishing the code or any suggestions to the Ajax?

Comment: Why are you reloading the page after the AJAX call -- Also, why are you doing in a form submit in the AJAX callback?

Comment: ^^ This.  If you're going to reload the page then why not just submit the form?

Comment: Well the form is on another page, so I want to submit that form, then I have to reload the current page as the data won't show up (title change) until after reload.

Comment: @EasyBB -- The point of AJAX is to not reload the page, you can easily use the callback from `.load` and display your new data.

Comment: `reload` will fire before AJAX completes...AJAX is asynchronous. Code you have makes little sense...should explain exact behavior wanted

Comment: Ok, though right now the point is, even with the reload it's not submitting the data. Say we are on link `/t123` the form to change the title is on `/post?method=editpost&t=123`

Comment: Ok @charlietfl I'll try it without the reload. I'll try the callback `.load` first then let you know.

Comment: @everyone I told you I stink at Ajax ;) I add the submit form in the ajax as I wasn't getting any results, most likely due to the `reload` like charlietfl said

Answer (score 0):

Ajax and "reload the page" should **not** be used in the same sentence.

With that in the clear, the easiest will be to create a pseudo-REST API via a new PHP "page" (and I'm guessing you're using PHP as you have mentined a "forum") and then to direct the data at that "page" which will "save" it.

The ajax call (from the page where the form is):

```
$('#form_name').submit(function(event) { 
  var $form = $( this ),
    form_field_name1 = $form.find( "input[name='form_field_name1']" ).val(),
    form_field_name2 = $form.find( "input[name='form_field_name2']" ).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourserver.com/api.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "form_field_name1": form_field_name1, "form_field_name2" : form_field_name1 },
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#output").html("Saving, please wait....");
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log('/API response received:', data);
      var result = new Boolean(data);
      if (result) {
        $("#output").html("Saved.");
      } else {
        $("#output").html("Not saved.");
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
      $("#output").html("ERROR when saving data: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });

  event.preventDefault(); // important, so that the page doesn't reload
});
```

The `api.php` page (in short):

```
$form_field_name1 = $_POST['form_field_name1'];
$form_field_name2 = $_POST['form_field_name2'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db_name");

$query= "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`field_name1`,`field_name2`) VALUES ('" . $form_field_name1 . "','" . $form_field_name2 . "')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error()); 

return $result;
```

Further reading: a guide for a proper PHP REST API: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Comment: I don't have access to the PHP itself